k8s : Calico node is not coming up
I am trying to bring up k8s cluster with calico. Calico node install-cni container is not coming up
root@stage:/etc# kubectl version
Client Version: v1.28.10
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.28.10

Calico install-cni log
2024-06-03 15:24:39.524 [INFO][1] cni-installer/<nil> <nil>: CNI plugin version: v3.26.3
2024-06-03 15:24:39.524 [INFO][1] cni-installer/<nil> <nil>: /host/secondary-bin-dir is not writeable, skipping
W0603 15:24:39.524362       1 client_config.go:618] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
2024-06-03 15:25:09.554 [ERROR][1] cni-installer/<nil> <nil>: Unable to create token for CNI kubeconfig error=Post "https://10.3.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/serviceaccounts/calico-cni-plugin/token": dial tcp 10.3.0.1:443: i/o timeout
2024-06-03 15:25:09.554 [FATAL][1] cni-installer/<nil> <nil>: Unable to create token for CNI kubeconfig error=Post "https://10.3.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/serviceaccounts/calico-cni-plugin/token": dial tcp 10.3.0.1:443: i/o timeout

my service cidr is not clashing with my host ip.
root@stage:/etc# cat /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubeadm.kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver.advertise-address.endpoint: 10.97.112.221:6443
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: kube-apiserver
    tier: control-plane
  name: kube-apiserver
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - kube-apiserver
    - --advertise-address=10.97.112.221
    - --allow-privileged=true
    - --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    - --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction
    - --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true
    - --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
    - --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
    - --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
    - --etcd-servers=https://127.0.0.1:2379
    - --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt
    - --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-kubelet-client.key
    - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
    - --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
    - --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
    - --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
    - --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
    - --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
    - --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
    - --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
    - --secure-port=6443
    - --service-account-issuer=https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
    - --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.pub
    - --service-account-signing-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key
    - --service-cluster-ip-range=10.3.0.0/23
    - --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key

Telnet on k8s svc doesn't work either
root@stage:/etc# kubectl get svc kubernetes
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.3.0.1     <none>        443/TCP   37m
root@stage:/etc# telnet 10.3.0.1 443
Trying 10.3.0.1...

`

I read all related questions but no luck
